# Make my Jquery code fit all links with class="trigger". Can't get next() to function

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, universal

html:

```
<a id="invitation" class="trigger" href="#"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
<a id="dummy" class="hide">Do something</a>
<div id="invitationbox"></div>
```

I get the jquery code to work when i do this:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
$('#invitation').load('invitation.php', function() {
$('#dummy').trigger('click');
});
});
```

But want it to work on several links with the class trigger... So how do i rewrite the code to work for more than one place?

Example:
(Can't get this to work...)

html:

```
<a id="anotherid" class="trigger" href="#"><img src="img.jpg"/></a>
<a class="hide">Do something</a>
<div id="anotheridbox"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
var contentId = $currentId + "box";
$($contentId).load('invitation.php', function() {
$(this).next("a").trigger('click');
});
});
```

Help me make my code simple thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your code there were some bugs:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

    // $currentId is never declared
    var contentId = $currentId + "box";

    // $contentId is never declared and the id selector should be begin with a #
    $($contentId).load('invitation.php', function() {
        // $(this) is the element related to contentId, so there is 
        // no next("a") to trigger a click on
        $(this).next("a").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Try this instead:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    var $trigger = $(this);
    $("#" + $trigger.attr('id') + 'box').load('invitation.php', function() {
        $trigger.next("a").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: thnx for the reply hunter!
$trigger returns [object object]. When i did alert($trigger) to check. Tried the code and it doesn't seem to work, the load function never runs and the click doesn't happen. :/

Comment: `$trigger` should be an `[object object]`. In this case it's a jQuery object. There must be some other bug in your code elsewhere. Use a debugger like Chrome Inspector, Firebug, or IE Developer Tools to see what's up.

Comment: Got it to work like this:
Probably not the best way of doing it, but works for me :)

    $(".trigger").click(function() {
     var $currentId =$(this).attr('id');
     var $newlink = $currentId + '.php';
     var $newcontent = '#' + $currentId + 'box';
     var $nextlink = '#' + $(this).next().attr('id');
        $($newcontent).load($newlink, function() {
      $($nextlink).trigger('click');
        });
    });
Thanks for your help :>